# How to tween a timestamp to a specific time

Tags: javascript, animation, timestamp, tween, gsap

I have a fake clock on screen with a time of day:

```
<div class="time">9:14<sup>am</sup></div>
```

I want to make a function to be able to tween that time to another arbitrary time,
 so that the clock would actually progress through the seconds and hours until it hit the new time(pseudocode):

```
var currentTime = {
  time: 9:14am
}
function changeTime(newTime){
  TweenMax.to(currentTime,.5,{
    time: newTime
  });
}

changeTime(12:32pm);
```

So in the case above, the minutes would go up by one until they hit 60, then increment the hours by one and reset to zero, then increment again to 60, etc, until they hit 12:32 (with the am switching to pm at 12:00pm).

Is there a way to do this with tweenmax and a timestamp? Or would I need to construct a custom function? Or perhaps is there a better way to tween time?

Comment: By tween you mean the literal morphing transition from number to the other? So other solutions such as the vertically rotating panels old clocks have or using opacity to fade out one number and fade in the next wouldn't work?

Comment: No - I just need the numbers to switch - it can be a hard cut between one number and the next, doesn't even need to fade. But it needs to progress through the minutes and hours sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this (and improve it, I did this quickly).

```
<script>
        var hour, minute, second, meridian, isAm;
        isAm = true;
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
        second = 0;

        function timerLoop () {
            second++;

            if(second > 59) {
                second = 0;
                minute++;
            }

            if(minute > 59) {
                minute = 0;
                hour++;
            }

            if(hour >12) {
                hour = 1;
                isAm = !isAm;
            }

            // update labels
            meridian = 'a.m.';
            if(!isAm) meridian = 'p.m.';
            console.log(hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + ' ' + meridian);

            setTimeout(function() {
                timerLoop();
            }, 1000);
        }


        timerLoop();
    </script>
```

I tested it for 2 mins only but the that part was working. 
You'll probably want to add leading zero's to the single digits  as I haven't done that. And once it is running as you want you can look at adding animations or fades to style it a bit better.